# Ruby - How to set data_uri (base64) filename with Shrine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, base64, shrine

I'm trying to set the filename to a base64 file uploaded with the Shrine gem with FileSystem store.

I tried modifying the `file.metadata[:filename] = 'test.png'`, but the filename still nil.

```
anex = Anex.new(file_data_uri: file) # file is a base64 string
resource.anexes << anex
resource.save!
```

shrine.rb

```
require "shrine"
require "shrine/storage/file_system"

Shrine.storages = {
  cache: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads/cache"), # temporary
  store: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads/store"), # permanent
}

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :cached_attachment_data # for forms
Shrine.plugin :data_uri # for base_64
Shrine.plugin :infer_extension
# Shrine.plugin :rack_file # for non-Rails apps
```

FileUploader.rb

```
class FileUploader < Shrine
  # plugins and uploading logic

end
```

Anex.rb

```
class Anex < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :anexable, polymorphic: true

  include FileUploader::Attachment.new(:file) # adds an `file` virtual attribute

  def url
    "#{ENV['FILE_STORAGE_URI']}#{self.file.url}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the filename by updating the `file_data` column after assigning the data URI:

```
anex = Anex.new(file_data_uri: data_uri)
file = anex.file
file.metadata["filename"] = "test.png"
anex.file_data = file.to_json
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. There's a way to change de id too (the actual file name)?

Comment: The upload location is generated in `Shrine#upload_location`, see https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine#location on how to override it.

Comment: See https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/blob/master/doc/changing_location.md